# MySQL - SELECT only 2 rows from each 'group'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row

I'm trying to create a `query` that will serve as filter for displayed information.

Specifically I want this query to show up to 2 rows with this same `position` value.

I've written this code so far, but it only shows one of each category, i'm not sure what am I doing wrong, could you help me please?

```
SELECT name, surname, position, value, points FROM
    (SELECT name, surname, position, value, points, 
    @num := IF(@type = position, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
    @type := position AS dummy 
    FROM players 
    WHERE (name LIKE '%$searchphrase%' OR surname LIKE '%$searchphrase%') 
    AND value >= '$minvalue'
    AND value <= '$maxvalue'
    GROUP BY position) AS x WHERE x.row_number <= 2
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN $filter=0 THEN points END DESC, 
    CASE WHEN $filter=1 THEN points END ASC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=2 THEN value END DESC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=3 THEN value END ASC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=4 THEN surname END DESC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=5 THEN surname END ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  However, MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  Plus, you have a `group by position` in the subquery.

So I think you might want:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT name, surname, position, value, points, 
             (@num := if(@type = position, @num + 1,
                         if(@type := position, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) AS row_number
      FROM players p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @num := 0, @type := '') params
      WHERE (name LIKE '%$searchphrase%' OR surname LIKE '%$searchphrase%') AND
            value >= '$minvalue' AND value <= '$maxvalue'
      ORDER BY position
     )  x
WHERE x.row_number <= 2
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, thanks you very much Gordon!